# __iter__ (iterator and generator)

Tags: python

I read a book about advanced topics in python.
The author was trying to explain the generator.

This was his example to explain:

```
class rev:
    def __init__(self,data):
        self.data = data
        self.index  = len(data)
    def __iter__(self):
        return self
    def __next__(self):
        if self.index == 0:
            raise StopIteration
        self.index = self.index - 1
        return self.data[self.index]

def main():
    reve = rev('zix')
    for i in reve:
        print(i)

if __name__=='__main__':
    main()
```

The main idea of this code is to reverse generators.
The output is :

```
x
i
z
```

The thing I found hard to understand is this part:

```
def __iter__(self):
    return self
```

Can someone explain it to me?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [confused \_\_iter\_\_](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1610371/confused-iter)

Comment: no the problem i have whit __iter__

Comment: Doesn't [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1610583/5827958) solve your problem?  The question is a little bit hard to read, but the accepted answer confirms that it is the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do `for x in xs`, `xs` has to be an **iterable**, which means you can get an **iterator** out of it by `iter(xs)`, which you can do when `xs.__iter__()` is implemented. An iterator is required to implement `__next__()`, so that the `in` operator can consume it one by one by calling `next()` on it.

Now, in your case

```
reve = rev("hello") # is an iterable, as there is rev.__iter__()
rev1 = iter(reve)   # is an iterator, this is what rev.__iter__() returns
rev2 = next(rev1)   # now go on calling next() till you get StopIteration
```

**Type the above snippet in REPL.** Run it a few times. You will get a feel for it.

Answer (score 1):

The `iterator` protocol is comprised of two methods:

- `__iter__`, and
- `__next__`

Also, a requirement is that `__iter__` returns `self` -- so if you have an `obj` that is an `iterator` then

```
obj is iter(obj) is obj.__iter__()
```

is true.

This is a good thing because it allows us to say `iter = iter(obj)` and if `obj` was already an iterator we still have the same object.

Comment: why should  __iter__  returns  self

Comment: @zixrobert: Because Python says so ;).  Also because it allows us to say `this_iter = iter(obj)` and if `obj` was already an iterator we still have the same object.  This is a good thing.

Comment: `__iter__` doesn't have to return self, it just needs to return an object that has a `__next__` (`next` in python 2). Consider these two cases: `f=open('deleteme.txt', 'w');iter(f)==iter(f)` is `True` while `l=list();iter(l)==iter(l)` is `False`. File objects return `self` because they only have one iterator based on the current file pointer and internal buffers. Lists return instances of a different class, `list_iterator`. Each iterator is a separate "cursor" that goes through the list independently.

Comment: @tdelaney: If object `a` has an `__iter__` method that returns `a`, then `a` is an iterator; if instead it returns object `b`, and `b` has a `__next__` and an `__iter__` that returns `b`, then `b` is the iter*ator*, and `a` is an iter*able*.  So yes, files are iter*ators* and lists are iter*ables*.  In the context of the question: Yes, it must `return self` because it is an iterator.

Comment: I just didn't want OP to come away thinking that `__iter__` must return `self` "because Python says so". Python says that `__iter__` must return an object that supports the iterator protocol.

Answer (score 0):

Since your class provides an implementation for `next()` it returns `self` so the caller will call that when looping over your object. In contrast, if you only wanted to wrap a data structure that already provides an implementation of `__iter__` and `next` (e.g. list), you could return `self.data.__iter__()` from your class. In that case the caller would call `next()` defined on that object when doing a loop or list comprehension let's say.

```
class rev:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data
        self.index = len(data)

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def next(self):
        if self.index == 0:
            raise StopIteration
        self.index = self.index - 1
        return self.data[self.index]


class rev2:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data

    def __iter__(self):
        return self.data.__iter__()


def main():
    for i in rev('zix'):  # str doesn't provide implementation for __iter__
        print(i)
    for i in rev2(['z', 'i', 'x']):  # list does so no need to implement next
        print(i)
```