# Are tuples, list, dictonaries, sets objects of the same class?

Tags: python

I'm learning python online on my own, and I was reading about iterators when this question came out.

Are all iterators objects of one unique class in python, where this class has all the lists, sets, tuple methods?

Comment: No, iteration is determined by `__iter__()` and `__next__()` methods on the object. See SO question [Iteration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36489670/python-iter-iterator-and-generator).

Answer (score 2):

Iterator is not a type. It's a protocol that different types can implement in their own way. A type is an iterator if it defines a method named `__next__` that either returns some value or raises `StopIteration` when called. The iterator protocol is used by passing an instance of an iterator type to `next`, which does nothing but invoke its argument's `__next__` method.

```
# Python equivalent to the builtin:
_next_sentinal = object()
def next(obj, default=_next_sentinal):
    try:
        return obj.__next__()
    except StopIteration:
        if default is not _next_sentinal:
            return default
        raise
```

An *iterable* is another part of the iterator protocol: a class that implements a method named `__iter__` that returns a value of some type that implements `__next__`. The implementation of `__iter__` does not have to return the same object that calls the method, or even a value of the same type as the object. (See [@kaya's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71009631/1126841) for some examples.)

The most common use of the iterator protocol is by a `for` loop. The code

```
for x in foo:
    ...
```

uses `foo.__iter__` to get an iterator for `foo`, then repeatedly calls the `foo` iterator's `__next__` method to get values to assign to `x`.

Answer (score 1):

No, iterators are not all instances of the same class (except in the trivial sense that they are all instances of the base class `object`). You can verify this using the `type` function on many different iterators; most standard container types and other iterable types built into the language have their own iterator classes.

```py
>>> iterables = [list(), tuple(), set(), frozenset(), dict(), dict().values(), str(), range(1)]
>>> for c in iterables:
...     print(type(c), 'has iterator type', type(iter(c)))
... 
<class 'list'> has iterator type <class 'list_iterator'>
<class 'tuple'> has iterator type <class 'tuple_iterator'>
<class 'set'> has iterator type <class 'set_iterator'>
<class 'frozenset'> has iterator type <class 'set_iterator'>
<class 'dict'> has iterator type <class 'dict_keyiterator'>
<class 'dict_values'> has iterator type <class 'dict_valueiterator'>
<class 'str'> has iterator type <class 'str_iterator'>
<class 'range'> has iterator type <class 'range_iterator'>
```

This works because all of the different iterator classes implement the [iterator protocol](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#iterator-types), and Python uses [duck typing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing) which means Python code generally doesn't check that objects are instances of the "correct" class, instead it just uses those objects in a certain way and it works as long as those objects have the right attributes and methods to be used in that way (i.e. if they waddle like a duck and quack like a duck...).

Comment: Bah, I forgot to talk about iterables in my answer...